# Invalid resource directory name in android

Tags: android, android-mapview, gmsmapview

I am using android studio, I added gms library in my android project. And after build I got error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> D:\Android\Mejodo\app\src\main\res\values-11: Error: Invalid resource directory name
```

I read in other articles that, these folders are for different screen sizes. But I have only three values folders (values, values-11, values-v11), So >=11 version handle with values-11 folder.

But I don't know how to solve it.
Can I delete these folders ?
 Please suggest something.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

v11 in values-v11 is a qualifier for Android sdk version v11.

Take a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html.

So I think "values-11" folder is unnecessary and wrong.

Comment: Thank you, I removed values-11 folder, and it's working... Thx

Answer (score 1):

Delete all unnecessary folder containing empty folder
Like above  "values-11" folder is unnecessary  so delete it
After that clean the project.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. Indeed `values-11` is not a valid name, instead it has to be replaced by `values-v11` in order to compile. So basically I would suggest to move anything you had in folder `values-11` and move it into the `values-v11` one.